# Spring boot does not execute update statement affecting multiple rows

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, sql-update

I have 2 classes Student and Course  .
Student has many to many relationship with course

```
@Entity
public class Course {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "primary_course")
    private boolean primaryCourse;
}


@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "course_like",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_course_like_student_id_")),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_course_like_course_id")))
    Set<Course> likedCourses;
}
```

The repository class is like this

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Long> {


    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE course SET primary_course = false WHERE course.id IN ( SELECT cl.course_id  FROM course_like cl  WHERE cl.student_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void resetPrimaryByUserProfileId(Long studentId);
}
```

The idea is when the student add a new course and if it is set as primary course I call this function to reset any course that set as primary course. So there can only be one primary course for a student.

But when i run this..

there is data in the database matching this requirement but when this get executed 0 rows get affected.

the console shows

```
Hibernate: 
    update
        course
    set
        course.primary_course = false 
    WHERE
        course.id IN (select
            pa.course_id 
        from
            course_like pa 
        where
            pa.student_id = ?)
```

in Intellij idea "query console" if i set the student id and run this query it works fine.

There are no errors in the console also

I am really puzzled why the query is not getting executed.

Can anyone provide some help?

Comment: can anyone provide some help on this?

Comment: Could you please add code where you call this query? Is method transactional?

Comment: And another question related to the logic: if I understand correctly, table Courses contains all courses, not courses per just 1 student. So, lets say student#1 sets courseX as prime course and courseY as additional, when student#2 selects courseY as his/her prime course and courseX as additional, and at this point courseX will be set to prime=false for all students (as it is in the common Courses table) and student#1 will loose his/her settings